# Non-significant variable in regression

Tags: regression, p-value

How do you explain a significant variable (p-value less than 0.05) in a linear regression equation in layman terms?

Comment: $p<0.05$ indicates a significant variable. Did you mean a p-value greater than 0.05?

Answer (score -1):

A non-significant variable is one which you have not yet proven to have a "true" coefficient that is non-zero.

Comment: I have edited for clarity of grammar, but I do think this provides an answer - albeit brief - to the question.

Comment: Plesse feel free to delete the answer, if one-liners are inappropriate. I do not understand this as a statistical question that needs explanation and context in the answer. It is just a tip, on how to explain to outsiders and I found, those want short and easy explanations.